# Invalid Python Syntax Error

Tags: python

Inside the shell, I get the following response when I try to import my program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "tweet.py", line 26
        print "Favorited: %s" % (result['text'])
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why does `print "Favorited: %s" % (result['text'])` return an error? Googling has been unhelpful, this was working for me earlier...

Update, I'm running the following version of Python:

```
Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.6.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jun 28 2013, 22:20:13) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
```

Update again, here is the function:

```
def fetch_tweet(tweet):
    try:
        result = t.favorites.create(_id=tweet['id'])
        print "Favorited: %s" % (result['text'])
        return result
    # when you have already favourited a tweet, this error is thrown
    except TwitterHTTPError as e:
        print "Error: ", e
        return None
```

**Update #3 - found the error!**

Turns out my python interpreter really hated a bit of code I had at the top, which was messing with `print` somehow - I deleted `from __future__ import print_function` from the top of the file and everything started working smoothly.

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: Updated with information above...

Comment: It might simply be an indentation issue. Try to reduce it to the simplest program that reproduces the problem, and re-post with the entire code. I'm sure you'll get helpful answers.

Comment: Could you post a bit more code?

Comment: Thanks y'all, updated with more code.

Comment: This code runs smoothly on my computer (I replaced the function call and the exception with dummy code)

Comment: @SteinarLima I'm still getting the same error. I don't know why.

Comment: Try to run [this](http://pastebin.com/S8XHCjhM) code separate from the rest of your program. If that code works, the problem is not your Python installation, at least.

Comment: I found the error! Will write it in the question above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you got it working, but here's the explanation:

Python 3 changed how printing works for various reasons. The big change is that `print` is now [a function](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print) instead of a statement (this is helpful because it allows you to, say, pass parameters to it if you want to change things like where it prints to, whether to terminate with a newline, etc)

So when you had the line:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

It was using Python 3 printing, but you're running in Python 2. One solution (as you found) is to remove the import, but you could also change the `print` statement to a function. For simple statements like this you just need to add parens, so this would have worked:

```
print("Favorited: %s" % (result['text']))
```

These would also work:

```
print("Favorited: {}".format(result['text']))

print("Favorited:", result['text'])
```